# SQL join issue across three tables returning results when conditions not met

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run a query that will look across a person table, appointment table, and reminder table.

I want to return only people that have had at least 1 appointment, do not have a future appointment, and do not have an active reminder in the system.

```
SELECT  p.person_ID
from people p   
WHERE exists (
select 1 from appointments e where e.person_id=p.person_id 
    AND e.appt_kept_ind='Y' )
AND not exists (
   select 1 from appointments s where s.person_id=p.person_id 
   AND CONVERT(DateTime, s.apptdate, 112) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
AND not exists (
   select 1 from reminder re where re.person_id=p.person_id 
   AND  CONVERT(DateTime, re.return_date, 112) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

Edit: After taking feedback i removed the left joins; i noticed that one of the issues was the active='y' someone could have an active reminder, but the reminder could be in the past and still "active" so i updated it to also check if their reminder date was only in the future and exclude those records.

Edit: Request for the schema

```
Person
   person_id UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL PK
   firstname nvarchar NOT NULL
   lastname nvarchar NOT NULL
   ....

Appointments
   appointment_ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PK  
   person_ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
   apptdate nvarchar NOT NULL
   apptKept nvarchar (N or Y)

Reminder
    reminder_id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PK
    person_ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
    return_date nvarchar NOT NULL
    Active nvarchar (N or Y)
```

I've got a few issues: returns multiple results of people, do i even need the joins if all the data i need is in the people table? Finally, its fairly slow.

Comment: i dont know what the a.kept does, but left joining two tables will make it return matches from both tables, and will create duplicate entries if you hit two entries in the same table. so in your case, if two appointments exists for one user, it will give duplicate person-rows because of that join. It seems that you are doing all the filtering based on those subselects, so i guess the joins is probably not needed. left joins are also slower then inner joins, so that might explain some of your performance issues

Comment: After posting i worked on it a bit more and came up with this:

Answer (score 0):

There are a view things that come into mind:

1. you get additional columns if a person has more than one appointment or more than one reminder (due to the left join); BTW, I don't think that it is necessary to join reminder here, as you do not make use of the result.
2. you use correlated subqueries in the where-part after your two left joins. In theory, each of this subqueries is evaluated for each of the (probably duplicate) tuples returned by this join. Depending on the data, I assume that uncorrelated subqueries could be faster.

Try the following (hope syntax is correct, as I cannot try it out without a schema). The approach is to check the appointments in one rush by preparing a table `appaggr` that evaluates for every person `person_id` the max of `kept` (which must be `Y` if any tuple exists), and in the same run evaluates the latest appointment (which must be before `current_timestamp` if no future appointment exists).  Joining (note: not left joining) this table to person table should return all people that have had an appointment and that do not have any future appointment. Further, checking reminders is transformed to an uncorrelated subquery; this should work more efficiently if there are not to much people with active reminders:

```sql
SELECT   p.firstname, p.lastname,  p.person_ID, 
from people p 
join (select a.person_id, max(a.kept) as maxkept, max(CONVERT(DateTime, a.apptdate, 112)) as maxdate 
           from appointments a
           group by a.person_id
           having maxkept='Y' and maxdate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) appaggr on p.person_id = appaggr.person_id
where p.person_id not in (select r.person_id from reminder r where r.active='Y')
```

Comment: I added the scheme, when i try to use your query it says maxkept is not defined